# base type is not CLS-compliant

Tags: c#

I'm using [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) and all is working great except I'm getting the following warning:

> 'UnitTests.TestRecordClassMap': base type
>   'CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvClassMap' is not CLS-compliant

For this code:

```
namespace UnitTests
{   
    public class TestRecord // Test record class
    {
        ...
    }

    public sealed class TestRecordClassMap : CsvClassMap<TestRecord>
    {
        public override void CreateMap()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Any ideas how I can clear it?

Comment: Change the code of the base class to resolve the issue, use a different base class, or stop asking for CLS compliance

Comment: I don't know what's wrong specifically as you haven't posted the code for CsvClassMap, but this might give you an idea of what's necessary to correct it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The CsvClassMap code is part of the CsvHelper library. I don't want to stat messing with that so I'll live with it for now. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Why do you need CLS compliance?

Comment: I don't, I just thought it was good practice.

Comment: I used to be, 10 years ago.